# Jest test assertion, expect a nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

When I do the below expect in jest with native test

```
expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
     order_type: expect.arrayContaining(['1']),
     number: '',
     ouser_ids: expect.arrayContaining(['user_id1']),
     payment_type: expect.arrayContaining(['2']),
     start_date: old_Date,
     end_date: current_date,
     state: 'all',
    });
```

I'm getting the following error

```
   Object {
                "end_date": "2022/06/07",
                "number": "",
            -   "order_type": ArrayContaining [
            +   "order_type": Array [
                  "1",
                ],
            -   "ouser_ids": ArrayContaining [
            +   "ouser_ids": Array [
                  "user_id1",
            -   ],
            -   "payment_type": ArrayContaining [
            -     "2",
                ],
            +   "payment_type": Array [],
                "start_date": "2022/06/01",
                "state": "all",
              },
```

I have also tried without expect.arrayContaining() still getting the same error
I'm I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `expect.arrayContaining` inside the properties of an object that you are expecting. You will need to use an alternative approach as follows:

```
const objectCalledWith = mockOnChange.mock.calls[0][0];
expect(objectCalledWith.order_type).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['1']));
// and so on for the other property values...
```

Explanation:

`mock.calls` contains all of the calls made on `mockOnChange`, where we specifically choose to access the first call via `[0]`. The second `[0]` retrieves the first argument that the `mockOnChange` function was called with and we assign it to `objectCalledWith` variable. We can then use this variable to inspect and validate its properties using the `expect` matchers as necessary.